# Does deep cloning also create new parent record?

Tags: apex, clone

I am running below code

```
Account a1 = new Account(name='a1');
insert a1;
Account a2 = new Account(name='a2', parentId = a1.id);
insert a2;
Account a3 = new Account(name='a3', parentId = a2.Id);
insert a3;

Contact c = new Contact(lastName='c1', accountid = a3.Id);
insert c;

Contact cc = [select id,name,accountid,account.name,account.parentId,account.Parent.name,account.parent.parentid,account.parent.parent.name from contact where id=:c.id];
system.debug('#####-'+cc);
system.debug('#####-'+cc.account);
system.debug('#####-'+cc.account.parent);
Contact copy = cc.clone(false,true,false,false);
system.debug('$$$$$$-'+copy);
system.debug('$$$$$$-'+copy.account);
system.debug('$$$$$$-'+copy.account.parent);
```

Output is

```
22:57:31.392 (392570856)|USER_DEBUG|[12]|DEBUG|#####-Contact:{Id=00328000003rlFAAAY, Name=c1, AccountId=00128000004PkxhAAC}
22:57:31.392 (392870600)|USER_DEBUG|[13]|DEBUG|#####-Account:{Id=00128000004PkxhAAC, Name=a3, ParentId=00128000004PkxgAAC}
22:57:31.393 (393028713)|USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|#####-Account:{Id=00128000004PkxgAAC, Name=a2, ParentId=00128000004PkxfAAC}
22:57:31.393 (393287506)|USER_DEBUG|[16]|DEBUG|$$$$$$-Contact:{Name=c1, AccountId=00128000004PkxhAAC}
22:57:31.393 (393388123)|USER_DEBUG|[17]|DEBUG|$$$$$$-Account:{Id=00128000004PkxhAAC, Name=a3, ParentId=00128000004PkxgAAC}
22:57:31.393 (393486302)|USER_DEBUG|[18]|DEBUG|$$$$$$-Account:{Id=00128000004PkxgAAC, Name=a2, ParentId=00128000004PkxfAAC}
```

Now, my question is why it is preserving Id on parent record even though I have set preserveId flag false. What is exact process of deep cloning. How do I clone parent records without using any custom code. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: @KiranMutturu It is 30.0

Answer (score 2):

Because the preserve ID is ONLY for the ID field of the record itself. Cloning preserves relationships. From the docs (yea, they do have important information) on the sObject Class:

> If set to true, the method creates a full copy of the sObject. All
>   fields on the sObject are duplicated in memory, including relationship
>   fields. Consequently, if you make changes to a field on the cloned
>   sObject, the original sObject is not affected.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_clone

Note that your copy contact does NOT have an ID value as you set preserveID to false.

Comment: So what is meant by "All fields on the sObject are duplicated in memory, including relationship fields."? Does that mean if I modify cc.account then copy.account will not be affected?

Comment: @doga - Correct - Again from the docs: `Consequently, if you make changes to a field on the cloned sObject, the original sObject is not affected.` (and vice versa)

Comment: I run the code. If I go to a3 record. I see two contact in contact related list. This mean a3 is shared between two contacts. And I also run the same code with isDeepClone false. It gave me same result.